# Execute powershell command in foreach loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I am trying to execute aws s3 cp command in Powershell. I have a list of files which I defined in an array-like below.

`$filearray = ("file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "file4.txt", "file5.txt")`

Now when I am trying to copy these files from s3 using aws s3 cp command nothing works.

`$filearray | foreach { "aws s3 cp s3://<bucket_name/path_to_file/$_ . --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id 12345-abcxzd" }`

I tried below as well. But it didn't work. Can someone point out the mistake I am doing?

`foreach ($element in $filearray) { "aws s3 cp s3://<bucket_name/path_to_file/$element . --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id 12345-abcxzd" }`

Now I have added variables to my aws command also which will be like below when the loop executes.

`$kms_key_option="--sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id 12345-abcxzd"`
`$s3_location="s3://<bucket_name/path_to_file/"`

`foreach ($element in $filearray)  { & aws s3 cp $s3_location/$element $current_location $kms_key_option }`

But there is a catch in this. Only the first 2 variables in command block work as variables rest 2 do not work as variables. i.e. `$current_location $kms_key_option` So the problem statement is changing here a little bit.

Note: I have aws cli installed on my windows machine it works with normal command but it doesn't work in  foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the & operator.

```
foreach ($element in $filearray) { & "aws s3 cp s3://<bucket_name/path_to_file/$($element) . --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id 12345-abcxzd" }
```

Comment: This works somewhat but throws CommandNotFoundException in my case for aws s3 cp command.

Comment: I was able to get it working after resolving the CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

I'd say try it without the Quotes in the foreach loops?

```
foreach ($element in $filearray) {
    aws s3 cp s3://<bucket_name/path_to_file/$element . --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id 12345-abcxzd
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Though the command execution is successful it does not achieve copy operation.